# Responsive navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make this navbar responsive on <= 480px devices as it disappears in these devices and an icon is showing & when I click on it thee navbar shows below it.

It worked but I realized that when I resize the screen back again to >480px the navbar is still hidden because the style "display:none" is inline.

Can anyone suggest better solution ?

```js
let counter = 1;    
let myinterval = setInterval(startInterval,2000);
function startInterval(){
    document.getElementById("select" +counter).checked = true;
    counter++
    if(counter > 3){
        counter = 1
    }
}
for(let i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[i].onclick = function(){
        clearInterval(myinterval)
    }
}
let drop = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0]
drop.onclick = function(){
    let menu = document.getElementById("navdrop")
    if(menu.style.display === "none" || menu.style.display ===""){
        menu.style.display = "flex"
    }else{
        menu.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

```css
*,*::after,*::before{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height:5000px;
    padding-top:71.7px
}
.container1{
    height:96.5vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
.container1 nav{
    display: flex;
    height:11%;
    padding: 10px 140px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown{
    display:none;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:50%;
    width:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    justify-content: center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown:hover div{
    background-color: black ;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown div{
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgb(211, 208, 208);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.container1 nav .logo svg{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
.container1 nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 1%;
    align-items: center;
    width:43%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap:4%
}
.container1 nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.150vw,1.3rem)
}
.container1 nav ul li a:hover{
    color:black
}
.container1 nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#777;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
.container1 nav ul li:last-child button{
    border:none;
    padding:0px 14px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff);
    color:white;
    font-size:clamp(0.9rem,1.1vw,1.2rem);
    height:90%;
    transition:all 0.2s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.container1 nav ul li:last-child button:hover,.main button:hover{
    color:rgb(194, 194, 194)
}
.main{
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-image: url("second.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.main{
    padding-left:13%;
    color:White;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:5%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.main::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.2
}
.main h1{
    font-size:clamp(2rem,3vw,50px);
    z-index: 1;
}
.main p {
    width:43.5%;
    line-height: 1.7;
    z-index: 1;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: clamp(0.9rem,1.15vw,2rem)
}
.main button{
    width:max-content;
    padding:10px 12px;
    border:none;
    font-size:clamp(1.2rem,1.2vw,1.5rem);
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color:white;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer
}
.container2{
    height:82vh;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.container2::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
    height:1px;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.row1{
    height:40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:7%
}
.container2 h1{
    font-size:clamp(1.8rem,2.3vw,40px)

}
.row2 h2{
    font-size:clamp(1.2rem,1.6vw,1.6rem)
}
.container2 p{
    font-size: clamp(0.9rem,1.1vw,1.3rem);
}
.row1 p {
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.row2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap:35px;
    height:60%;
    padding:0 150px;
}
.row2 div{
    text-align: center;
    width:32%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center ;
    gap:18px;
}
.row2 div p{
    text-align: left;
    line-height:1.6;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.row2 div i{
    width:110px;
    height:60px;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: clamp(2.5rem,4vw,3rem);
}
.container3{
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.slider{
    width:60%;
    height:70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides{
    width:500%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
}
.slides input{
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width:20%;
    transition: 1s;
}
.slide img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.navigation_manual{
    width:60%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:10px
}
.manual_btn{
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid #eee;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.manual_btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.manual_btn:hover{
    background-color:black
}
#select1:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: 0%;
}
#select2:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#select3:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: -40%;
}
.navigation_auto{
    position:absolute;
    display: flex;
    width:60%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:33.45%;
}
.navigation_auto div{
    border:2px solid #23E3C9;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;    
}
.navigation_auto div:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#select1:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn1{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
#select2:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn2{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
#select3:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn3{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
.container4{
    background-color: #0C0633;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column ;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:6.5% 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    gap:20px
}
.container4 h1{
    font-size:clamp(2rem,2.8vw,2.5rem)
}
.container4 p{
    width:72%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.container4 button{
    border:0;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container4 button:hover{
    color:rgb(194, 194, 194)
}
.container5{
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.contain{
    width:75%;
    height: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.7fr 0.3fr 1fr ;  
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;  
}
.leftUp{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}
.rightUp{
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.rightUp ul{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around; 
    gap:6px;        
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
.rightUp ul li{
    padding-left:10px
}
.rightUp ul li::marker{
    content: '\f058';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #A07FFF;
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem,1.5vw,1.5rem);
}
.rightUp ul li h1{
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem,1.8vw,1.8rem);
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.rightUp ul li p{
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.2vw,1rem);
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555555
}
.downall{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    display: flex;
}
.downall div{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.downall div img{
    width:clamp(125px,12vw,300px)
}
.leftUp img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container6{
    height:45vh;
    display: flex;
    gap:15px;
    padding:10px 11%;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;   
}
.container6 div{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:12px
}
.container6 h2{
    font-size: clamp(1rem,1.5vw,24px);
}
.container6 p{
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.1vw,16px);
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div a{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    padding:7px ;
    transition:0.2s ease
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div a:hover{
    color:#3b1bff
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:first-child{
    width:100%;
    height: clamp(100%,4vw,200%);
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height:clamp(100%,4vw,200%);
    width:13.5%;
    border: 0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color: white;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:nth-child(2):focus{
    outline: 0 solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width:782px) {
    .container1 nav ul{
       margin-right: 17%;
    }
    .container1 nav {
        padding:10px 70px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:624px){
    .container1 nav ul{
        margin-right: 38%;
     }
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .container1 nav ul{
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height:max-content;
        gap: 20px;
        padding-left: 27.5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li a{
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li:last-child{
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li:last-child button{
        padding:5px
    }
    .container1 nav .dropdown{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column ;
        gap:3px;
    }
    .container1 nav{
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:10px 0 ;
        gap:0;
    }
    .container1 nav .logo{
        width:70%;
        height:120%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav .logo svg{
        width:20%;
        height: 80%;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container1">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="33" height="34" viewBox="0 0 33 34">
                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 34)">
                  <polyline stroke-linecap="round" points="4.81 32.607 .28 28.112 .28 .3 27.688 .3 27.688 28.112 10.068 28.112 10.068 10.133 22.373 10.133"/>
                  <polyline stroke-linecap="round" points="28.19 .3 32.72 4.795 32.72 32.607 5.312 32.607 5.312 5.074 22.653 5.074 22.653 23.064 10.068 23.055"/>
                  <path d="M5.31355932 5.07573214L10.3474576 10.413444M27.6864407 27.8312406L22.6525424 23.0553932"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <ul id="navdrop">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
                <li><button>Download</button></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="drop1"></div>
                <div class="drop2"></div>
                <div class="drop3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Posuere lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="row1">
            <h1>Vivamus laoreet</h1>
            <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.
                Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="one">
                <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                <h2>Consectetur</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                <h2>Malesuada</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                <h2>Phasellus</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slides">
                <input type="radio" id="select1" name="slide"> 
                <input type="radio" id="select2" name="slide"> 
                <input type="radio" id="select3" name="slide">
                <div class="slide imgone"><img src="slide1.jpg"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="slide2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="slide3.jpg"></div>
                <div class="navigation_auto">
                    <div class="auto_btn1"></div>
                    <div class="auto_btn2"></div>
                    <div class="auto_btn3"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation_manual">
                    <label for="select1" class="manual_btn"></label>
                    <label for="select2" class="manual_btn"></label>
                    <label for="select3" class="manual_btn"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container4">
            <h1>Vivamus laoreet</h1>
            <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi.</p>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container5">
            <div class="contain">
             <div class="leftUp"><img src="comp.png"></div>
             <div class="rightUp">
                 <ul>
                 <li class="firstrow">
                     <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                     <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                 <li class="secondrow">
                    <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                    <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                 <li class="thirdrow">
                    <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                    <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="downall">
                 <div>
                 <img src="logo1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="logo2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="logo3.png" alt="">
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container6">
            <div class="one">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet consectetur dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <h2>Do you like ? Share this !</h2>
                <div class="socials">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
                <p>© Domain Name | Website created with Mashup Template/Unsplash</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <h2>Subscribe to newsletter</h2>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="button" value="OK">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution for you would be to add a media query at the very bottom of your css file that makes your `#navdrop` element always visible whenever the screen is greater than 480px. You can achieve this by using `min-width` in the media query instead of `max-width`. By using `!important` you can override even inline styles. It's not great practice to overuse `!important` but I think if it's just this case it should be fine. See the proposed code below.

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    #navdrop{
        display: flex !important;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a listener that gets executed `onresize` that can override the inline style whenever the detected screensize is greater than 480px. See the proposed function below.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ()=>{
    if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].clientWidth > 480){
         document.getElementById("navdrop").style.display = "flex"
    }
});
```

In the snippet I only use the css but you can add the onresize logic anywhere in your JS, preferably towards the top.

```js
let counter = 1;    
let myinterval = setInterval(startInterval,2000);
function startInterval(){
    document.getElementById("select" +counter).checked = true;
    counter++
    if(counter > 3){
        counter = 1
    }
}
for(let i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("label")[i].onclick = function(){
        clearInterval(myinterval)
    }
}
let drop = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0]
drop.onclick = function(){

    let menu = document.getElementById("navdrop")
    if(menu.style.display === "none" || menu.style.display ===""){
        menu.style.display = "flex"
    }else{
        menu.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

```css
*,*::after,*::before{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height:5000px;
    padding-top:71.7px
}
.container1{
    height:96.5vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
.container1 nav{
    display: flex;
    height:11%;
    padding: 10px 140px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown{
    display:none;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:50%;
    width:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    justify-content: center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown:hover div{
    background-color: black ;
}
.container1 nav .dropdown div{
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgb(211, 208, 208);
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.container1 nav .logo svg{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
.container1 nav ul{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 1%;
    align-items: center;
    width:43%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap:4%
}
.container1 nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.150vw,1.3rem)
}
.container1 nav ul li a:hover{
    color:black
}
.container1 nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#777;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
.container1 nav ul li:last-child button{
    border:none;
    padding:0px 14px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff);
    color:white;
    font-size:clamp(0.9rem,1.1vw,1.2rem);
    height:90%;
    transition:all 0.2s ease;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.container1 nav ul li:last-child button:hover,.main button:hover{
    color:rgb(194, 194, 194)
}
.main{
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-image: url("second.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
.main{
    padding-left:13%;
    color:White;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:5%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.main::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.2
}
.main h1{
    font-size:clamp(2rem,3vw,50px);
    z-index: 1;
}
.main p {
    width:43.5%;
    line-height: 1.7;
    z-index: 1;
    word-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: clamp(0.9rem,1.15vw,2rem)
}
.main button{
    width:max-content;
    padding:10px 12px;
    border:none;
    font-size:clamp(1.2rem,1.2vw,1.5rem);
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color:white;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer
}
.container2{
    height:82vh;
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top:10px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}
.container2::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
    height:1px;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
.row1{
    height:40%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap:7%
}
.container2 h1{
    font-size:clamp(1.8rem,2.3vw,40px)

}
.row2 h2{
    font-size:clamp(1.2rem,1.6vw,1.6rem)
}
.container2 p{
    font-size: clamp(0.9rem,1.1vw,1.3rem);
}
.row1 p {
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
.row2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap:35px;
    height:60%;
    padding:0 150px;
}
.row2 div{
    text-align: center;
    width:32%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center ;
    gap:18px;
}
.row2 div p{
    text-align: left;
    line-height:1.6;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.row2 div i{
    width:110px;
    height:60px;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: clamp(2.5rem,4vw,3rem);
}
.container3{
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.slider{
    width:60%;
    height:70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides{
    width:500%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
}
.slides input{
    display: none;
}
.slide{
    width:20%;
    transition: 1s;
}
.slide img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.navigation_manual{
    width:60%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:10px
}
.manual_btn{
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid #eee;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.manual_btn:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.manual_btn:hover{
    background-color:black
}
#select1:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: 0%;
}
#select2:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: -20%;
}
#select3:checked ~ .imgone{
    margin-left: -40%;
}
.navigation_auto{
    position:absolute;
    display: flex;
    width:60%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top:33.45%;
}
.navigation_auto div{
    border:2px solid #23E3C9;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;    
}
.navigation_auto div:not(:last-child){
    margin-right: 30px;
}
#select1:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn1{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
#select2:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn2{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
#select3:checked ~ .navigation_auto .auto_btn3{
    background-color:#000 ;
}
.container4{
    background-color: #0C0633;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column ;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding:6.5% 0;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    gap:20px
}
.container4 h1{
    font-size:clamp(2rem,2.8vw,2.5rem)
}
.container4 p{
    width:72%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.container4 button{
    border:0;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container4 button:hover{
    color:rgb(194, 194, 194)
}
.container5{
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.contain{
    width:75%;
    height: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.7fr 0.3fr 1fr ;  
    grid-template-rows: 70% 30%;  
}
.leftUp{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}
.rightUp{
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.rightUp ul{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around; 
    gap:6px;        
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
.rightUp ul li{
    padding-left:10px
}
.rightUp ul li::marker{
    content: '\f058';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #A07FFF;
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem,1.5vw,1.5rem);
}
.rightUp ul li h1{
    font-size: clamp(1.2rem,1.8vw,1.8rem);
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.rightUp ul li p{
    line-height: 1.7;
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.2vw,1rem);
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #555555
}
.downall{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    display: flex;
}
.downall div{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.downall div img{
    width:clamp(125px,12vw,300px)
}
.leftUp img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container6{
    height:45vh;
    display: flex;
    gap:15px;
    padding:10px 11%;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;   
}
.container6 div{
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap:12px
}
.container6 h2{
    font-size: clamp(1rem,1.5vw,24px);
}
.container6 p{
    font-size: clamp(0.8rem,1.1vw,16px);
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div a{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    padding:7px ;
    transition:0.2s ease
}
.container6 div:nth-child(2) div a:hover{
    color:#3b1bff
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:first-child{
    width:100%;
    height: clamp(100%,4vw,200%);
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:nth-child(2){
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height:clamp(100%,4vw,200%);
    width:13.5%;
    border: 0;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,#8b62ff 0,#3b1bff) ;
    color: white;
}
.container6 div:nth-child(3) div input:nth-child(2):focus{
    outline: 0 solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width:782px) {
    .container1 nav ul{
       margin-right: 17%;
    }
    .container1 nav {
        padding:10px 70px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:624px){
    .container1 nav ul{
        margin-right: 38%;
     }
}
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .container1 nav ul{
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height:max-content;
        gap: 20px;
        padding-left: 27.5px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li a{
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li:last-child{
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav ul li:last-child button{
        padding:5px
    }
    .container1 nav .dropdown{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column ;
        gap:3px;
    }
    .container1 nav{
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:10px 0 ;
        gap:0;
    }
    .container1 nav .logo{
        width:70%;
        height:120%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .container1 nav .logo svg{
        width:20%;
        height: 80%;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
   
}

@media screen and (min-width:480px) {
    #navdrop{
        display: flex !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="33" height="34" viewBox="0 0 33 34">
                <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 34)">
                  <polyline stroke-linecap="round" points="4.81 32.607 .28 28.112 .28 .3 27.688 .3 27.688 28.112 10.068 28.112 10.068 10.133 22.373 10.133"/>
                  <polyline stroke-linecap="round" points="28.19 .3 32.72 4.795 32.72 32.607 5.312 32.607 5.312 5.074 22.653 5.074 22.653 23.064 10.068 23.055"/>
                  <path d="M5.31355932 5.07573214L10.3474576 10.413444M27.6864407 27.8312406L22.6525424 23.0553932"/>
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <ul id="navdrop">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Components</a></li>
                <li><button>Download</button></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="drop1"></div>
                <div class="drop2"></div>
                <div class="drop3"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Posuere lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="row1">
            <h1>Vivamus laoreet</h1>
            <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.
                Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="one">
                <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                <h2>Consectetur</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                <h2>Malesuada</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
                <h2>Phasellus</h2>
                <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="slides">
                <input type="radio" id="select1" name="slide"> 
                <input type="radio" id="select2" name="slide"> 
                <input type="radio" id="select3" name="slide">
                <div class="slide imgone"><img src="slide1.jpg"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="slide2.jpg"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="slide3.jpg"></div>
                <div class="navigation_auto">
                    <div class="auto_btn1"></div>
                    <div class="auto_btn2"></div>
                    <div class="auto_btn3"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navigation_manual">
                    <label for="select1" class="manual_btn"></label>
                    <label for="select2" class="manual_btn"></label>
                    <label for="select3" class="manual_btn"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container4">
            <h1>Vivamus laoreet</h1>
            <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi.</p>
            <button>Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="container5">
            <div class="contain">
             <div class="leftUp"><img src="comp.png"></div>
             <div class="rightUp">
                 <ul>
                 <li class="firstrow">
                     <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                     <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                 <li class="secondrow">
                    <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                    <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                 <li class="thirdrow">
                    <h1>Dui augue</h1>
                    <p>Auctor augue mauris augue neque. Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</p>
                 </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
             <div class="downall">
                 <div>
                 <img src="logo1.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="logo2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="logo3.png" alt="">
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container6">
            <div class="one">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sit amet consectetur dolor</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
                <h2>Do you like ? Share this !</h2>
                <div class="socials">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                </div>
                <p>© Domain Name | Website created with Mashup Template/Unsplash</p>
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                <h2>Subscribe to newsletter</h2>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="button" value="OK">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```